# How to handle success response with [ ]

Tags: android, retrofit

[image]

I have to handle an API that response with [] if there is no value to return. How to get this response in retrofit onResponse? Currently, it return an error in onFailure of retrofit

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Maybe I could do something like checking if (response.body() == null) in onResponse once onResponse is called.

Comment: please share your retrofit Api-Definition for that endpoint. I guess you expect an object but you receive an array

Comment: Post your response data if there is value to return also

Answer (score 0):

You should get response like this

```
ArrayList<ResponseClass> responseList= response.body();
if(responseList.size() > 0) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While write JSON responce in service (it may be in .net or .php)  you need to write this responce in terms of object like "{}".
If you want to get responce in array then write in [] and for object write in {}.